# azure APIM I need hide section Authorization in portal developer operation details

Tags: azure-api-management

We did a new release of the development portal in the Azure API Management and it showed the following message:

> Creating a new revision or changing revisions will automatically update the portal to the latest version of the software. Content saved in the administrative version of the portal will not be changed.

Which caused that in my portal it now shows me in the box in the transaction detail section all the information to request the authorization token with `oauth 2.0`

[image: Section Authorization]

How can I hide the authorization element so that it does not show in my portal for security reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Authorization section in the API reference pages surfaces only public information required for clients to authenticate against your API. It doesn't show the secret configuration of your OAuth server. This information has always been publicly accessible, now we just visually render it. If, for some reason, you need to hide the public OAuth server details, you can remove the authorization server configuration from your API Management service. Keep in mind that it will also affect the test console.

If you still consider it a problem, please open a GitHub issue in the developer portal repository: https://aka.ms/apimdevportal and precisely describe your concern.